# AngularJS: dynamic form creation

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to dynamically create a form with AngularJS.
See the code on plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/lgSlbQlRcY26HhPzbj63/preview.

The problem is in adding a void option inside a select: I would like to use it as a label for the field.
So I created the void option in order to bind to element label:

```
<option value="">{{element.label}}</option>
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE (ideally from IE8) rendering is not working and option displays "{{element.label}}" (at least until I click the select).

Does someone know why or how to fix it?

Thanx

Comment: I never target IE when using modern frameworks like AngularJS. There's too many breaking changes, even the official Angular source code is full of ugly non-sense hacks for IE. But will be interesting to see if somebody got a solution for this :)

Comment: Did you take a look in this notes for IE http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie ?

Comment: yes... it does not seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am on a mac, with no IE.  I even tried to use www.browserstack.com.

The jsFiddle I was using wouldn't even load the home page for jsFiddle in IE 8.

In www.browserstack.com I used IE 9 and it did work in the jsFiddle.

Here is the jsFiddle if you want to mess with it.

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/4znn1tef/)

Since I can't test in IE 8 on jsFiddle, or Plunker as they both don't load in IE 8 on www.browserstack.com, try this out and see if you can trick it to work by using another approach.

```
<!-- <option value="">{{element.label}}</option> gray this out -->
<option value="">Age Range</option> // just for your initial cell value
<option value="element.label"></option> // The items
```